# Escape single quote (') in raw string r'...'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I want it to print out

```
this is '(single quote) and "(double quote)
```

I use the following (I want to use raw string 'r' here):

```
a=r'this is \'(single quote) and "(double quote)'
```

But it prints out

```
this is \'(single quote) and "(double quote)
```

What is the correct way to escape ' in a raw string?

Answer (score 17):

Quoting from [Python String Literals Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals),

> When an `'r'` or `'R'` prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal `r"\n"` consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase `'n'`. **String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string;** for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote.

There are two ways to fixing this

1. Using multiline raw strings, like mentioned in the section [Python Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

   ```
   print(r"""this is '(single quote) and "(double quote)""")
   # this is '(single quote) and "(double quote)
   ```
2. Using [String literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation),

   ```
   print(r"this is '(single quote) and " r'"(double quote)')
   # this is '(single quote) and "(double quote)
   ```

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> a=r'''this is '(single quote) and "(double quote)'''
>>> print(a)
this is '(single quote) and "(double quote)
```

Comment: @william007 that makes it a mutliline string, which doesn't end until the next matching triple quote.

Comment: The question is "What is the correct way to escape `'` in a raw string", not "how can I avoid needing to escape `'` in a raw string"...

Comment: @ChrisMartin True, well to answer that to OP, in this specific case its not possible.

Comment: @ChrisMartin As I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27467935/1903116), it is not possible, but there are two alternatives to this problem.