# Replace capturing group with return value from passing capturing group to a function

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a specific capturing group with the return value from passing said capturing group to a function. The following code is in Python:

```py
def translateWord(word):
    ... do some stuff
    return word

def translateSentence(sentence):
    # ([alpha and ']+) [non-alpha]*
    # keep the () part, ignore the rest
    p = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z']+)[^a-zA-Z]*")

    # find each match, then translate each word and replace
    return p.sub(lambda match: translateWord(match.group(1)), sentence)
```

This code replaces the entire match as opposed to the capturing group.

Example of bad output:

```py
>>> sentence = This isn't my three-egg omelet.
>>> sentence = translateSentence(sentence)
>>> print(sentence)

Isthayisn'tyayymayeethrayeggyayomeletyay
```

The code needs to output this instead:

`Isthay isn'tyay ymay eethray-eggyay omeletyay.`

The `translateWord()` function should **only** operate on a string input. I could test to see *what kind* of input the function is taking and change behavior based on that, but that defeats the purpose. How would one do this correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape single quote (') in raw string r'...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467870/escape-single-quote-in-raw-string-r) (or maybe not?)

Comment: What exactly is the error message (including traceback)?

Comment: Wait - you can't use `lambda` in a `string %` expression. What did you think that was doing?

Comment: As stated in the question, I am trying to replace a capturing group with the return value from a function taking in the capturing group as a parameter. This is the way I thought it would work, and it clearly doesn't.

Comment: Can you show some example inputs with expected results?

Comment: I just updated it to show an example of what my code is doing specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, just try:

```
return p.sub(lambda match: translateWord(match.group(1)), sentence)
```

It looks like you got confused about what to pass as the second parameter to re.sub: you pass the actual function (in this case, the lambda expression), no need to try to embed that in a string.

If you want to change just a group though, the `re` methods don't give direct support to it - instead, you have to recreate the a single string with the whole match, replacing the groups you want to change yourself.

The easier way is to expand your "lambda" function into another multi-line function that will do that mangling for you. It can then use the `.regs` attribute on the match object it receives to know the groups limits  (start and end), and build your replacing string:

```py
def replace_group(match):
    sentence = translateWord(match.group(1))
    matched = match.group(0)
    new_sentence = matched[:match.regs[1][0]] + sentence + matched[match.regs[1][1]:] 
    return new_sentence
```

Comment: I need this to replace a specific capturing group, not the entire match.

Comment: it is just a matter of passing the match object to your full function, and manipulate the string there, untill you replace what you want. Inside the fucntion you can use normal string operations, and even other regular expression operations if needed - whatever your function returns  will replace the whole match

Comment: I need the `translateWord()` function to **only** allow a string as input.

Comment: The match object does have a `.regs` attribte with the limits for your groups - I will update the answer so it works for you

Comment: (the hint to find out this kint of thing is get hold of a regexp match object in an interactive Python console, and introspect it with `dir` and calls - one can learn and understand it much better than just reading the docs)